# Troubleshooting failed file upload for FineUploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm using React version of FineUploader and getting both "PUT request failed" and "put blob call failed" errors when I try to upload a file -- see below:
[image]

The next line "Received error response" doesn't really tell me anything. Just gives me the HTML of my page.

I did set up my CORS settings with PUT, DELETE and OPTIONS -- see below:
[image]

and the following shows my FineUploader instantiation.[image]

The link to the fine uploader implementation is at http://ingridapp.azurewebsites.net/home/test

What could be causing this issue?

UPDATE: 
I'm actually not seeing any calls to my Azure container. Checked both in Chrome and Fiddler. I don't think a call to Azure is being made.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the entire response payload?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I added an update to the original post. I'm not seeing a call to my Azure container. I see the call to my API to get the SAS for the Azure call but after that I'm not seeing anything being sent to Azure. Am I misinterpreting this or an actual call to Azure is not happening at all.

Comment: Something in your code is causing Fine Uploader to make an ajax request to http://ingridapp.azurewebsites.net/home/test to upload the file. I'm guessing the code you posted in your question does not reflect the actual code running on that site. And without source maps, I can't really tell you anything further.

Comment: It is the actual code. I just did a copy and paste before posting it here. I'll re-bundle it and update the site to see if that will make a difference.

Comment: without source maps, I can't really tell you anything further, as I can't really see any readable code

Comment: I'm back to this project. I uploaded the new files. Would you be able to take a look at this again? I also pointed the signature and uploadSuccess URLs to a custom domain i.e. not the generic Azure URL. Also enabled HTTPS.

Comment: BTW, the new URL is https://ingrid.cool/home/test